# illegal assignment from object to id Error?

Tags: apex, compile-error

I have written following code to insert records on junction object.

```
public static List<PDCN__c> addSelectedPDCNs(List<String> selectedRecords, String groupId) {
        system.debug('Entering addSelectedPDCNs');
        system.debug('Selected Records are-->'+selectedRecords);
        system.debug('Group Id is-->'+groupId);

        List < PDCN__c > lstAddId = [SELECT Id from PDCN__c where Name IN: selectedRecords];
        system.debug('Record Ids Are-->'+lstAddId);

        List<PDCNGrpJunc__c> lstJunc = new List<PDCNGrpJunc__c>();

        for( PDCN__c  pdcn : lstAddId ) {
            system.debug('Inside For Loop-->'+pdcn);
            PDCNGrpJunc__c juncRec = new PDCNGrpJunc__c();
            juncRec.PDCN__c = pdcn;
            juncRec.PDCN_Group__c = groupId;
            lstJunc.add(juncRec);
        }
        //insert lstJunc;
        try{
            system.debug('Trying Insert');
            system.debug('');
            insert lstJunc;
                }
         catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.debug('Exception Occured='+e.getMessage());
        }

        return lstAddId;
    }
```

I am getting error in juncRec.PDCN__c = pdcn; line as :-

> Illegal assignment from PDCN__c to Id

Why do I get this error? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 7):

So the field `juncRec.PDCN__c` is a Lookup field, (Consider it as a text/ID field)

where as in your loop `pdcn` is an object/record.(Not a text field)

In your code

```
juncRec.PDCN__c = pdcn;
```

What you are trying to do is assign an Object to a Text/Id field and hence you get an error. You can solve this by using id `juncRec.PDCN__c = pdcn.Id;`

```
for( PDCN__c  pdcn : lstAddId ) {
            system.debug('Inside For Loop-->'+pdcn);
            PDCNGrpJunc__c juncRec = new PDCNGrpJunc__c();
            ***juncRec.PDCN__c = pdcn.Id;***
            juncRec.PDCN_Group__c = groupId;
            lstJunc.add(juncRec);
        }
```